# Returning agent set's output into dataframe from loop

Tags: for-loop, netlogo, rnetlogo

This is a RNetlogo problem. Suppose, I have a agentset in Netlogo, where each farmer represent one patch. I have some "setup" and "go" procedure over the patches. I wish to go for 10 ticks. At every tick I wish to extract the values in R against some variables for agents (farmers or patches). Following is my code with limited parameters -

```
for(i in 10){
  NLCommand("set CropPirce ", 16, "setup")
  NLDoCommand(i, "go")
  print(NLGetAgentSet(c("ticks", "pxcor", "pycor", "Profit"), 
                           "patches with [a? = TRUE]")) # a? means if farmer adopted the crop
}
```

Now, how can I extract the printed values for each tick steps into a dataframe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store it R, you could make an empty dataframe and then `rbind` each call to `NLGetAgentSet()`.

With this test model:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 3
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    rt random 90 - 45
    fd 1
  ]
  tick
end
```

Make your empty dataframe:

```
vars <- c("ticks", "who", "pxcor", "pycor")

dfBase <- data.frame(matrix(
  NA,
  nrow = 0,
  ncol = length(vars),
  dimnames = list(NULL, vars)
))
```

Run the model (assuming it's already opened):

```
NLCommand("setup")

for (i in 1:10) {
  NLCommand("go")
  
  dfBase <- rbind(dfBase, (NLGetAgentSet(vars, 'turtles')))
}

> head(dfBase); tail(dfBase)
  ticks who pxcor pycor
1     1   0    -1     0
2     1   1    -1    -1
3     1   2    -1     1
4     2   0    -2    -1
5     2   1    -1    -2
6     2   2    -2     1
   ticks who pxcor pycor
25     9   0    -8    -2
26     9   1    -1    -7
27     9   2    -7     3
28    10   0    -9    -2
29    10   1     0    -7
30    10   2    -8     2
```

Comment: Thank you so much Luke! Your answer worked nicely for me.

Comment: @KaziMasel - Glad to be of help! Happy coding